# Pandas filter date column by next month

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have df with a column as 'Date' - this is in the format `2021-12-01` always beginning of month. How to filter by next month onwards?

currently using below that filters by current month and onwards..

```
df_next_month= df[(df['Date']> pd.Timestamp('today').strftime('%Y-%m'))]
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for filter greater like today month period:

```
print (df)
        Date
0 2021-12-01
1 2022-01-01
2 2022-02-01
3 2022-03-01

df_next_month= df[(df['Date'].dt.to_period('m') > pd.Timestamp('today').to_period('m'))]
print (df_next_month)
        Date
2 2022-02-01
3 2022-03-01
```